# trigger to update a column on insertion or updation of another column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to update `image_updated_at` field of `recycle_center` table if there is any insertion or update on `image_url` field of same table(recycle_center). I have tried this one::

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF image_url ON recycle_center
BEGIN

    UPDATE recycle_center SET image_updated_at=NOW()
    WHERE old.id=new.id

END
```

But, it shows an error message. How to fix it??

Comment: Do the [auto-update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) properties of `TIMESTAMP` not suffice?

Comment: Wich is the error message it shows? Edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need trigger for this problem. Simply, for image_updated_at field, make type=TIMESTAMP, default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and Attributes= on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.